# Advertisement appearing in the middle of posts

Tags: html

A website I'm managing seems to have these advertisements appearing in an ABSOLUTE position on every page no matter how long the page is. So, sometimes, this advertisement link/image thing just meshes with the text and is incredibly annoying.
I'm assuming it has something to do with a footer positioning problem, I have tried to read up on this but I can't seem to understand what needs to be done.

an example of the problem is here, scroll down a tiny bit and you will see the offensive red links mixing with the picture

http://www.nussusave.org/what-we-do/green-hostels/

Comment: Well, sounds like your invoking something to pop upon on load or whatever. Your best bet is to work with a `fixed` position element, and use the javascript your using to calculate the overall needed position of the element based on its height/width vs the browsers view port height/width and position it accordingly from that.

Comment: If you aren't doing this yourself, the consider the possibility that the site your working on has been hijacked, and has likely had bad javascript injected into it through some entry point (unknown) and your pages have this code serving this up.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
.siteframe {
    height: 100%;<--remove  this
}
```